# HTML5 Video Fallback Image Issue Loading Messy

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I have a fallback poster image inside my html5 video preload settings that loads messy while waiting for the actual video to load as it sits then suddenly disappears when the video loads. My question is can I code this transition more neatly and how can I not make the image flash then disappear so messy just right before the video loads? Also when video cannot be loaded such as on mobile/and handheld devices how to remove the play button rendered to the fallback image?

Here are my settings:

```
    <div class = "sudirlayheader-container">
    <div class = "sudirlayvideo-container">
        <video preload = "auto" autoplay = "autoplay" loop = "loop" volume = "0" poster="video/Dubai-Wallpaper.png">

  <source src = "video/sudirlayvid.mp4" type = "video/mp4">
  <source src = "video/sudirlayvid.ogg" type = "video/ogg">
  <source src = "video/sudirlayvid.webm" type = "video/webm">
  <source src = "video/sudirlayvid.mov" type = "video/mov">


      </video>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my own solution, apparently the html5 code that I originally have is correct and the best way to do things but the way to make a smooth transition is mainly just a little editing of css and picture schemes on my behalf. So sum it up I just took a snapshot of the main pic and lightened the frame so that if the video loads but takes time the fallback image just seems to be a cool fade in effect and the css is used to remove the play button when the video does not load on mobile/and handheld devices etc.

Now my main css looks like this:

```
.header-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 900px;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
}

.video-container {

    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

}

video {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 100%;

}
```

**Notice this line fixes the weird button showing up on the fallback image when video doesnt load**

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {
  display: none;
}
```